# Can third party cookies override first party cookies?

Tags: javascript, security, cookies, third-party-cookies

Can third party cookies override first party cookies?

Let's say I have session id stored in the cookie "SESSIONID", and then my page loads dozen of scripts from other domains that set their third party cookies, can they override first party cookies?

Comment: Have you tried it? Use the [browser console (dev tools)](//webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/8525) (hit `F12`) and look into the **Web Storage** tab (and the **Cookies** subtab). Cookies are identified by origin, among other things, so, normally, cookies of different domains are stored separately.

Comment: I am sorry I have worded my question completely wrong... I wanted to ask whether third party cookies can set lots of cookies resulting in deleting the first party ones due to reached browser cookie limits.

Comment: [Edit] your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Cookies are restricted to the domain that set them.